# How to deal with cross heap references in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

It is clear to me how to deal with cross heap references in Xamarin Android:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/
http://www.slideshare.net/Xamarin/advanced-memory-management-on-ios-and-android-mark-probst-and-rodrigo-kumpera

How to deal with it with a Xamarin Forms app running under android?

Comment: Hopefully that is something Xamarin.Forms handles for you. Are you having any problems?

Comment: No problem (yet). I have experience with Xamarin Android and I am now familiarizing with Xamarin Forms.